# How to disable previous dates while still displaying the previous dates?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I used "`minDate : dateToday`" and "`minDate : 0`" but then the previous date is not displaying.

For example if i enter a today's date and when checked tomorrow, the Database still has yesterday's date but the date displayed will be tomorrow's.

How can i resolve this problem?

code used

```
$('#startDate,#endDate,#dateEntered').datepicker({
        minDate : dateToday,
        maxDate : "+10Y",
        buttonImage: "static/images/calender.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        constrainInput: true
    });
```

Comment: You can start by posting some code.

Comment: The behaviour you describe as i understand it is exactly how i would expect datepicker to work. If you could provide a sample, maybe i could better understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/f6qJF/1/

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    maxDate : "+10Y",
    buttonImage: "static/images/calender.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    constrainInput: true,
    beforeShowDay: check
});

function check(date) {
    if (date > new Date()) return [true];
    else return [false];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I had to use the datepicker's [`beforeShowDay` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) and remove the `mindDate` option.

Initialise like this:

```
$('#startDate,#endDate,#dateEntered').datepicker({
        maxDate : "+10Y",
        buttonImage: "static/images/calender.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        constrainInput: true,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) { 

           if (date != previousDate && date < dateToday) { //you will need to save the previous date in a variable
               return [false, "", "Date Unavailable"];
           }               
           return [true, ""];
        }
    });
```